# Se puede actualizar un token JWT expirado sin que el usuario lo note?

Tags: axios, promesas, laravel-6, vuejs, spa

Tengo el siguiente problema, creé un interceptor para que valide la respuesta del servidor y si la respuesta es `401` (token expirado o inválido) automáticamente solicite un nuevo token, lo amacene en el localstorage y realice la llamada original nuevamente, cabe mencionar que el SPA está desarollado con Laravel y Vuejs.

```
// Token Refresh
let isAlreadyFetchingAccessToken = false
let subscribers = []

function onAccessTokenFetched(accessToken) {
    subscribers = subscribers.filter(callback => callback(accessToken))
}

function addSubscriber(callback) {
    subscribers.push(callback)
}

export default {
    init() {
        axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
            return response
        }, function (error) {
            const status = error.response ? error.response.status : null
            // const { config, response: { status } } = error
            const { config, response } = error
            const originalRequest = config

            // if (status === 401) {
            if (status === 401) {
                if (!isAlreadyFetchingAccessToken) {
                    isAlreadyFetchingAccessToken = true
                    store.dispatch("auth/fetchAccessToken")
                        .then((accessToken) => {
                            isAlreadyFetchingAccessToken = false
                            onAccessTokenFetched(accessToken)
                        })
                }

                return new Promise((resolve) => {
                    addSubscriber(accessToken => {
                        originalRequest.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + accessToken
                        resolve(axios(originalRequest))
                    })
                })
            }
            return Promise.reject(error)
        })
    },
    login(email, pwd) {
        return axios.post("/api/auth/login", {email: email, password: pwd})
    },
    addCompany(comercial, razon_social, rfc, reg_patronal, address, city, cp, img, url, email, country, giro ) {
        return axios.post("/api/v1/companies", {comercial: comercial, razon_social: razon_social, rfc: rfc, reg_patronal: reg_patronal, address: address,  city: city, cp: cp, img: img, url: url,email: email, country: country, giro: giro, accessToken: axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem("accessToken")})
    },
    registerUser(name, email, pwd) {
        return axios.post("/api/auth/register", {displayName: name, email: email, password: pwd})
    },
    refreshToken() {
        return axios.post("/api/auth/refresh-token", {accessToken: localStorage.getItem("accessToken")})
    }
}
```

fetchAccessToken:

```
fetchAccessToken() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            jwt.refreshToken()
                .then(response => {
                localStorage.SetItem('accessToken', response.data.access_token)
                resolve(response) })
                .catch(error => { reject(error) })
        })
    }
```

refreshToken:

```
refreshToken() {
        return axios.post("/api/auth/refresh-token", {accessToken: localStorage.getItem("accessToken")})
    }
```

Pero cuando lo pongo en práctica desde un formulario sabiendo que el token ya expiró recibo la respuesta `401`:

```
title: "Error"
text: "token is expired"
iconPack: "feather"
icon: "icon-alert-circle"
color: "danger"
```

Y el interceptor no realiza la renovación del token si no hasta que reenvio la información nuevamente y me resulta molesto porque debería hacerlo desde que el servidor respondio `401` la primer vez.

Pienso que podría ser un error en las promesas del formulario pero llevo horas analizándolas y no encuento fallo, les dejo el código:

Formulario Wizard, valida 3 pasos si todo está correcto realiza el envío del payload a la acción AddCompanyJWT:

```
// register custom messages
Validator.localize('en', dict);
import jwt from "../../../http/requests/auth/jwt/index.js"

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            comercial: "",
            razon_social: "",
            email: "",
            city: "new-york",
            rfc: "",
            img: "",
            reg_patronal: "",
            address: "",
            giro: "planning",
            country: "chicago",
            cp: "",
            url: "",
            cityOptions: [
                { text: "New York", value: "new-york" },
                { text: "Chicago", value: "chicago" },
                { text: "San Francisco", value: "san-francisco" },
                { text: "Boston", value: "boston" },
            ],
            giroOptions: [
                { text: "Plannning", value: "plannning" },
                { text: "In Progress", value: "in progress" },
                { text: "Finished", value: "finished" },
            ],
            countryOptions: [
                { text: "New York", value: "new-york" },
                { text: "Chicago", value: "chicago" },
                { text: "San Francisco", value: "san-francisco" },
                { text: "Boston", value: "boston" },
            ],
        }
    },
    methods: {
        validateStep1() {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                this.$validator.validateAll('step-1').then(result => {
                    if (result) {
                        resolve(true)
                    } else {
                        reject(this.$vs.notify({
                            title: 'Error',
                            text: 'Correct all values.',
                            iconPack: 'feather',
                            icon: 'icon-alert-circle',
                            color: 'danger'
                        }));
                    }
                })
            })
        },
        validateStep2() {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                this.$validator.validateAll("step-2").then(result => {
                    if (result) {
                        resolve(true)
                    } else {
                        reject(this.$vs.notify({
                            title: 'Error',
                            text: 'Correct all values.',
                            iconPack: 'feather',
                            icon: 'icon-alert-circle',
                            color: 'danger'
                        }));
                    }
                })
            })
        },
        validateStep3() {
            // Loading
            this.$vs.loading()
            const payload = {
                companyDetails: {
                    comercial: this.comercial,
                    razon_social: this.razon_social,
                    rfc: this.rfc,
                    reg_patronal: this.reg_patronal,
                    address: this.address,
                    city: this.city,
                    cp: this.cp,
                    img: this.img,
                    url: this.url,
                    email: this.email,
                    country: this.country,
                    giro: this.giro,
                }
            }
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                this.$validator.validateAll("step-3").then(result => {
                    if (result) {
                        this.$store.dispatch('company/AddCompanyJWT', payload)
                            .then(() => {
                                this.$vs.loading.close()
                                resolve(true)})
                            .catch(error => {
                                this.$vs.loading.close()
                                reject(this.$vs.notify({
                                    title: 'Error',
                                    text: error.message,
                                    iconPack: 'feather',
                                    icon: 'icon-alert-circle',
                                    color: 'danger'
                                }))
                            })
                    }
                })
            })
        }
    },
    components: {
        FormWizard,
        TabContent
    }
}
```

La acción AddCompanyJWT recibe los datos del formulario y envía a la acción AddCompany que es la encargada de enviar toda la información al servidor:

```
AddCompanyJWT({ commit }, payload) {
      return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        jwt.addCompany(
            payload.companyDetails.comercial,
            payload.companyDetails.razon_social,
            payload.companyDetails.rfc,
            payload.companyDetails.reg_patronal,
            payload.companyDetails.address,
            payload.companyDetails.city,
            payload.companyDetails.cp,
            payload.companyDetails.img,
            payload.companyDetails.url,
            payload.companyDetails.email,
            payload.companyDetails.country,
            payload.companyDetails.giro,)
          .then(response => {
            // If there's user data in response
            if(response.data.company) {
              // Update company details
              commit("UPDATE_COMPANY_INFO", response.data.company)
              // Update status of WizardVerify
              localStorage.setItem("wizardVerify", true)
              // Navigate User to homepage
              router.push(router.currentRoute.query.to || '/')

                resolve(response)
            }
          })
          .catch(error => { reject(error) })
      })
    },
```

Acción AddCompany:

```
addCompany(comercial, razon_social, rfc, reg_patronal, address, city, cp, img, url, email, country, giro ) {
        return axios.post("/api/v1/companies", {comercial: comercial, razon_social: razon_social, rfc: rfc, reg_patronal: reg_patronal, address: address,  city: city, cp: cp, img: img, url: url,email: email, country: country, giro: giro, accessToken: axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem("accessToken")})
    },
```

Comment: Lo que ocurre hasta ahora es que envias el formulario con el token expirado falla la autorización obviamente y si lo envias de nuevo ya el token estaría renovado y funcionaría pero lo que quieres evitar que tengas enviar 2 veces el formulario. ¿Es eso lo que ocurre?

Comment: La función de la condicional en el interceptor es que si el servidor responde con 401 automáticamente ejecuta la renovación del token, en teoría esto debería suceder siempre que el servidor responda 401 y no sucede la primera vez, es decir no renueva el token, hasta la segunda, esto lo compruebo porque el token se almacén en el LocalStorage y noto que lo cambia hasta la segunda vez, pero no reenvía la solicitud original que falló

Comment: Y si, la intención si es evitar que el usuario tenga que enviar el formulario dos veces

Comment: Correcto pero no veo donde guardas el nuevo token en el local storage

Comment: Tienes razon, una disculpa ya actualice la pregunta, el token se almacena en la accion fetchAccessToken

Comment: ¿Aun no funciona? Si ese así, en mi codigo de una app vue recuerdo que para relanzar la peticion original (la que falló con 401) utilizo axios.request(originalRequest) en vez de axios(originalRequest). No tengo forma de asegurar que esto sea un problema en estos momentos por eso lo comento.

Comment: No lo es, o por lo menos no afecta el resultado, ya me duele la cabeza de tanto buscar

Comment: Establecer un tiempo de expiración al token tiene su motivación. Si un token está expirado, lo sensato es hacerlo saber al cliente y que el mismo tome la acción adecuada. Saltar automáticamente este paso, para no *molestar* al cliente, indica que tal vez no sea necesario o realmente no debas implementar un tiempo de expiración, ya que igualmente el usuario ni se entera que es posible tener una sesión vencida. Todo lo que intentes hacer a partir de allí, rompe la intención original del tiempo de expiración de la sesión o en este caso, del token. Saludos

Comment: No solo para eso, la expiración de los tokens te asegura que ese token no será utilizado en otro momento por alguien que ya no tiene autorización para entrar o que simplemente copiando el token de usuario autorizado tengas acceso a todo desde otro lugar. Cuando actualizas un token compruebas que el usuario realmente siga teniendo acceso y si es asi devuelves el token nuevo.

Comment: Se estan saliendo del tema, el objetivo no es saber la implementacion de los token en el sistema si no realizar la renovacion exitosamente, que se consigue con el codigo en la pregunta pero que tiene un error, esa es la intencion, encontrar el error

Comment: @AbdielHernandez, es correcto lo que mencionan sobre el uso de los token. Si de todos modos ante cualquier 401 vas a renovar el token, ¿Por qué no ignoras la expiración simplemente? ¿Y seguro que quieres renovar tokens vencidos? ¿No sería mejor que uses otros métodos o extiendas el tiempo de expiración?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es desde el backend enviar el tiempo en el que expira el JWT.

Cada que hagas una petición o cambies de ruta verifica si el tiempo esta por vencer, entonces ahí haz la petición para actualizar el token.
Aunque el actualizado del token se haga en segundo plano, las peticiones que se hacen mientras lo actualizas van a funcionar, y cuando termine las nuevas peticiones se harán con el token actualizado.

Esto me parece una buena manera porque si el usuario deja de usar por un buen tiempo el frontend superando el tiempo de expiración del token podrías solicitar las credenciales de nuevo, ya que puede ser otra persona que quiera acceder.

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar algo asi, me comentas

```
   public function refreshToken()
{

    $token = JWTAuth::getToken();

    try {
        $token = JWTAuth::refresh($token);
        return response()->json(['success' => true, 'token' => $token], 200);
    } catch (TokenExpiredException $ex) {
        // We were unable to refresh the token, our user needs to login again
        return response()->json([
            'code' => 3, 'success' => false, 'message' => 'Need to login again, please (expired)!'
        ]);
    } catch (TokenBlacklistedException $ex) {
        // Blacklisted token
        return response()->json([
            'code' => 4, 'success' => false, 'message' => 'Need to login again, please (blacklisted)!'
        ], 422);
    }

}
```